# c# is there any interface or pattern for optionally converting something?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an XElement representing a complex type.

Now that XElement could be an Asset, but it might not be.
The same for other types.

So I'd basically want to have something like

```
if ( element is Asset )
{
   Asset asset = element as Asset;
}
```

I don't think I can overload "is" and "as" so I'm wondering what a normal way to do this would be?

Comment: If you are using C# 7, you can do `if (element is Asset asset) { }`, which is a shortcut to what you are doing...

Comment: It looks like your code meets your requirements to me.

Comment: `is` and `as` are for checking actual types, not for user-defined conversions, which I *guess* you're talking about... how are you expecting an Assert conversion to occur? Can you give us a [mcve] which shows what you want in concrete terms? (While `XElement` isn't sealed, it would be odd to create a derived class from it, I would say.)

Comment: An xElement isnt an Asset.  I'd like to have a way to parse an xElement and determine if it parses successfully as an asset.  So it would be like overriding "is" to see if it the element has an <Asset> tag.  And also would need to overload "as" to actually convert the xElement to an Asset object.

Comment: Since `is` and `as` don't work (if there are no default cast operators), you could write an `bool Asset.TryParse(XElement element, out Asset asset)`, or (if you can't change the Asset class) an extension `static Asset Parse(this XElement element)`

Comment: If `XElement` doesn't derive from `Asset`, which it sounds like you might be trying to say, then you can't "convert". You need to create a new `Asset` object. You could create an [explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions), but I wouldn't unless it makes sense for your types.

Comment: Is there a *simple* test to apply here - I.e. if the `Name` of the XElement is `Asset` then it should either parse as an Asset or it's an error state or is this more complex with no such "local" clues and you just have to repeatedly attempt to parse it as each possible type?

Comment: I'm wondering if a user-defined conversion can return null.  I don't want to get an exception casting an XElement to an Asset if it isn't an asset, I'd want to return null.

Comment: you _could_ implement a user-defined conversion (explicit or implicit cast operator) that returns null if it's not an asset, but I would not do it as it breaks normal and expected c# behaviour: `var a = (Asset)element` _should_ really throw an `InvalidCastException` instead of returning null.

Comment: @Derek: It absolutely can return null, and that's what the user-defined conversions on `XElement` to nullable types do if the input element is null - but I believe they still throw if the data is simply inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
public class Asset
{
    public static bool TryConvert(XElement element, out Asset result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
if (Asset.TryConvert(element, out var asset))
{
    // Use asset here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx), then converting using `is`/`as` won't be possible, since the object you have is simply a wrapper around the XML text that may (or may not, per your question) represent an object of the correct type. Thus, you're not looking for conversion per se, what you're really looking for is *deserialization*. In that vein, you could try writing a parser:

```
public class Asset
{
    public static bool TryParse(XElement element, out Asset asset)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Asset));
        var reader = element.CreateReader();
        var result = serializer.CanDeserialize(reader));
        asset = result
            ? (Asset)serializer.Deserialize(reader)
            : default(Asset);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This fits with the pattern seen in [several](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) [in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx), which subsequently became the impetus (or at least a large portion thereof) behind the `out var` language feature mentioned in Daisy's answer